# Reverse Engineer CLI for Existing Oracle RDS Database

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Is there are way to reverse engineer CLI for an existing Oracle RDS Database ?

I already have an existing Oracle RDS Database and want to create another one with exact same parameters ( except database name ).

Instead of using GUI, I want to use CLI ( "aws rds create-db-instance" ).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [describe-db-instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/describe-db-instances.html) to get detailed information about your existing db instance. Then, based on the information obtained, you could create new db instance using `create-db-instance`.

If this is something that you will be doing often (i.e. creating same instances), it would be better to look into CloudFormation. This would allow you to provision reproducible db instances across different regions and accounts.

Comment: Thanks. I will try and post results here